# Zooming to feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, features, zoom, find

I have a shapefile that I created of points on each structure and address in the city. We have been working in ArcMap Desktop for 6 or 7 years and depend heavily on being able to simply go to "find", type in the address then zoom to it.

I have seen a "Zoom To Feature" plugin mentioned throughout QGIS Texts but I cannot find it using internet search. Does anyone know where I can find the "Quick Find" or "Zoom to Features" plugin?

Comment: Um, can I say yes and yes, I'm biased though. I already knew ArcGis so QGIS wasn't that much different. It's simple enough that I taught my 10-year-old how to use it for a school project. Yes there is a *zoom to selected feature(s)* in the table.. I recommend reading the documents and going through some of the on-line tutorials by yourself first and then use them as a teaching aid. BTW. generally the rule is *one question per question*, I don't mind in this case but others may hassle you about it.

Comment: Unrelated pearl of wisdom. As you are in a professional environment consider PostgreSQL/PostGIS - central storage, multi-edit environment and easy backup. Well supported by QGIS and other GIS platforms; even Esri suggests that it can be accessed read-only by ArcGIS... it's also FREE. Depending on your sever/network it can be faster than geodatabase to refresh/edit too. To get plugins the simplest way is go to the plugin manager and download it there.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson is right - one question per question - there is an edit button beneath it to enable you to edit it so that only the most important one remains, and it is easy to ask/research the other one separately (as per the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Comment: For learning resources, go to the [QGIS Documentation pages](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html) and take a peek at the User Guide, Training Manual, and others.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer could you please accept it? (click on check mark below up/down votes on left of the answer). Also great thing about QGIS it is highly customisable and there are companies/freelancers who will happily make/alter custom plugins to exactly match your needs most likely for small fraction of what you would have to invest with some other sw platforms.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 16):

Sure it is. Depending on what you need:

1. zoom to whole layer

   - right click on layer in Layers list and first item is "**Zoom to layer**"
2. zoom to selected feature(s)

   - select feature in map and click on icon "Zoom to selection" in the main toolbar
   - or right click on layer in layers list and choose "Open Attribute Table" (there is also icon in the main toolbar/attributes section for it), search for(Select feature using expression)/select feature and click on "**Zoom map to selected**"
3. pan map to selection

   - after selecting your feature click on icon "**Pan map to selection**" in the main toolbar
4. Quick Finder plugin

   - Quickly find features over all layers and online services, from a single place. (Plugins/Manage and install plugins - serch for Quick Finder)

Also for searching streets/locations in the whole world there is **GeoSearch plugin** which uses Google service to find/zoom to known locations. (Plugins/Manage and install plugins)

I believe **QGIS is very well made for easy learning** including doc and great community support.

For commands in QGIS open "Plugins/Python Console". But well, you need to learn python command first. Sure there are awful many including "zoom to selected feature".

Comment: 100% agree @miro, QGIS is very well made and well documented with how-tos, tutorials and help online. IMHO if you don't want to geoprocess to the same level as ArcGIS and are just interested in viewing, checking, mapping and/or capture it's as easy and powerful as professional (paid) software. Professional support is available (for a fee) and it's API isn't too difficult if you're that way inclined. As a general GIS/mapping package it's very mature and **excellent value for money**; our tests have shown that it is no slower than ArcGIS at the same tasks and sometimes quicker.

Comment: [Does not yet work with Geography types](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/223853/6052)

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned address search, you might be interested in the search plugins using Nominatim to geocode addresses: [OSM place search or osmSearch](http://anitagraser.com/2013/12/29/address-finders-in-qgis-osm-place-search-vs-osmsearch/)

[image]