# How can I get the default zoom level to work in QGIS for geography types?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-2.18

Create a table like this, and then add it as a layer to PostGIS. It has one simple geography, a line.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT ST_GeogFromText(
  'LINESTRING(-122.27172 37.80345,-122.27172 37.81549)'
) AS highway;
```

You can even create an index on it if you think it matters,

```
CREATE INDEX hwidx ON foo USING gist ( highway );
```

You can see the line in WKT in the table,

```
                      st_astext                      
-----------------------------------------------------
 LINESTRING(-122.27172 37.80345,-122.27172 37.81549)
```

Here is the table definition,

```
       Table "public.foo"
 Column  |   Type    | Modifiers 
---------+-----------+-----------
 highway | geography |
```

Yet, when I `Zoom to Layer` in QGIS, no joy! It just shows a blank screen. I am using QGIS 2.18.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like (as of Jan 2017) there's no support for determining the extent of a layer with geography column types. From [the source in (qgspostgresprovider.cpp)](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp#L3073):

```
QgsRectangle QgsPostgresProvider::extent() const
{
  ...
  if ( mSpatialColType == sctGeography )
    return QgsRectangle( -180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0 );
```

So for geography types the layer extent is always the entire globe. If you cast the geography to a projected geometry (even casting to a geometry in epsg:4326 should work) it will work correctly.

You can find [an open bug for this filed on 4/30/2015 here.](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12677), *Bug report #12677 (Open): Zoom to layer on PostGIS Table with geography type*.

Comment: Wow, bad ass job digging through the source at the speed of God to answer this. Thanks a ton. I was thinking that was the problem, but it seemed like such an omission and then again I have like no faith in my ability to use anything that has a mouse.