# Zooming to selected features from multiple layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, zoom

Is it possible to zoom to features selected from multiple layers in QGIS?

Comment: Quick Finder Plugin does this (may not work with newer versions of QGIS) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108372/zooming-to-feature-in-qgis

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no any option in menus, but you can zoom to features which are selected in multiple layers using Python.

Run the following script in QGIS Python Editor.

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

extent = QgsRectangle()

for layer in layers:
    extent.combineExtentWith(layer.boundingBoxOfSelected())
    
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(extent)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: I used it with a personal geodatabase layer and a shapefile and in that case it does not work even after I updated the extents of each layer